# EWARM compilation error - expression must have a constant value

Tags: iar

I'm using EWARM 6.6 from IAR Systems and get following compilation error I can't explain.

```
void testFunc(uint8_t* buf, uint8_t length)
{
  struct
  {
    uint8_t start;
    uint8_t data[length];
    uint8_t stop;
  }longframe;
  longframe.start = 1;
  memcpy( longframe.data, buf, length );
  longframe.stop = 2;
}
```

The compiler throws the error message: "Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value". This would be acceptable if the variable would be declared static or global but in this case I have no idea. I tried the same code with the GCC compiler and it worked fine. Anyone any ideas?

The criticized part is the length of data within the struct. It says the length has to be constant.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does the error point to a specific line of code?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining about the structure definition with an array of variable size. You may be able to accomplish this by switching your language from C to C++ in your project options. Your best bet is likely to work around using the variable sized array to begin with, but it would depend heavily on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In IAR Systems, Embedded Workbench 7.2, for the iccarm.exe C/C++ compiler, I ran into the same issue. I was getting an Error [Pe028] when trying to allocate an array on the stack with the length set by a function argument.

The documentation [here](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/005832/arm/doc/infocenter/iccarm_history.ENU.html) suggested adding --vla to my CFLAGS (iccarm.exe --vla ...), which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard (before C99 I think, although someone may correct me on this) does not allow arrays to be declared with the length as a variable.

However in the Project Options under C/C++ Compiler, Langauge 1 tab, Select C99 & the "Allow VLA" checkbox and you problem will be solved.

Comment: Just noticed the question is 3.5 years old. I expect they have solved this already!